# The reverse of maximal planar $\Rightarrow$ $m = 3(n-2)$?

Tags: graph-theory

It is well known that if $G$ is a simple maximal planar graph, then we have $m = 3(n-2)$ where $m$ is the number of edges in $G$ and $n$ is the number of vertices in $G$. But is it true for the reverse? If not are there any counterexamples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the graph made up of :

- $K_5$, the clique on $5$ vertices, name them $k_1,...,k_5$
- another vertex $v$ connected to $k_1$ and $k_2$

Now, our graph has ${5 \choose 2} + 2 = 12$ edges and $6$ vertices, which satisfies your formula. But this graph of course isn't planar because it contains $K_5$ as an induced subgraph.

If you meant to ask, "assuming $G$ is planar in the first place does $m = 3(n-2)$ imply that it is maximally planar ?". If it wasn't, we could add edges to it until we reach a maximal planar graph, which would then have $3(n-2) + 1$ vertices or more, contradicting the theorem.